# How to improve Allen NLP question answering performance

Tags: python, nlp, nlp-question-answering, allennlp

I am trying out Allen NLP pre-trained models for Q&A.

The online demo is here : https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension

I have created a python script to try out various models.

- [python script](https://gist.github.com/sujee/a22f6fa11065791314d5bfede434b516#file-qa-allen-nlp-py)
- [script output](https://gist.github.com/sujee/a22f6fa11065791314d5bfede434b516#file-output)

Here is the benchmark summary on my laptop

- Macbook Pro (2017)
- 2.9 Ghz Intel i7 quad-core
- 16 G memory

| Benchmark | transformer-qa | bidaf-model | bidaf-elmo-model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loading time | 31.6 seconds | 1.6 seconds | 13.8 seconds |
| questions |  |  |  |
| Who stars in The Matrix? | 794 ms | 62 ms | 1,798 ms |
| where does polar bear live | 2,211 ms | 96 ms | 7,125 ms |
| how much does a polar bear weigh | 2,435 ms | 98 ms | 7,082 ms |
| what is lightning | 1,361 ms | 69 ms | 3,173 ms |
| How many lightning bolts strike earth | 1,019 ms | 47 ms | 2,885 ms |

Looking at the [output](https://gist.github.com/sujee/a22f6fa11065791314d5bfede434b516#file-output)  I can see all 3 models are providing good answers.  I like the `transformer-qa` model but it takes a while (in the order of seconds) to predict.

Is there a way to speed up prediction times?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `transformer-qa` model contains more parameters, and as such is expected to take longer. One way to speed up inference time is to use a GPU; the speedup may not be significant if you are running `predict` on one instance at a time, running on batches should help there.

Comment: Hello akshitab, Can you give me any reference link or example for how can i process a paragraph in batches?